# Happstack get new StdGen for each request?

Tags: haskell, random, monad-transformers, happstack

I have a simple little Happstack application that shows a form with an email field and a random question field to help combat spam. To get a random number I use `getStdGen` in my `main` function and pass it along to my function which creates the html. The problem is that the same `StdGen` is used so my random value is not random unless I restart the application.

Here's what my `Main.hs` looks like:

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings, ScopedTypeVariables #-}                                                                                                

module Main where                                                                                                                                      

import Happstack.Lite                                                                                                                                  
import qualified Pages.Contact as Contact                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
import System.Random                                                                                                                                   

main :: IO ()                                                                                                                                          
main = do                                                                                                                                              
    gen <- getStdGen                                                                                                                                   
    serve Nothing $ pages gen                                                                                                                          

pages :: StdGen -> ServerPart Response                                                                                                                 
pages g = msum                                                                                                                                         
    [ dir "contact" $ Contact.page g                                                                                                                   
    ... Other irrelevant pages                                                                                                           
    ]
```

And here's the function that uses the `StdGen` to retrive a random question id:

```
getRandomQID :: StdGen -> Int                                                                                                             
getRandomQID g =                                                                                                                                       
    let (rpercent, _) = random g :: (Float, StdGen)                                                                                                    
        rid           = rpercent * questionsAmount                                                                                                    
    in  round rid                                                                                                                

questionsAmount :: (Num a) => a                                                                                                                        
questionsAmount = (fromIntegral . length) questions
```

**What is the most elegant way to solve this problem?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I wrote this question I found a solution that worked in the [Happstack crash course (templates)](http://happstack.com/docs/crashcourse/Templates.html).

In your route which has a return type of `ServerPart Response` you can use the `liftIO` monad transformer to be able to perform IO actions. There's this handy function called `randomRIO` with generates a random `Int` from an input of a tuple which two `Int`s as range, like this:

```
page :: ServerPart Response
page = do 
    randID <- liftIO $ randomRIO (0, max)
    ... Code to generate response ...
    where max = length questions
```

`randomRIO` can be found in `System.Random` and `liftIO` can be found in `Control.Monad.Trans`.